# Adding 3rd condition to ngClass is not working

Tags: css, angular

I am trying to add a 3rd condition to my ngClass. At first, I got the following two class to work in my ngClass to alternate the color of the rows

```
[ngClass]="{ totalrow:i%2 != 0, odd:i%2 == 0}"
```

I am trying to add a 3rd class and condition where the mat-list will show a border line for the top of the mat-list-item. However when I add the 3rd condition, it gives me an error

```
[ngClass]="{ totalrow:i%2 != 0, odd:i%2 == 0, borderTopClass : operator === 'fas fa-equals'}"
```

I get the following error which is confusing to me

> Parser Error: Missing expected : at column 47 in [{ totalrow:i%2 != 0,
>   odd:i%2 == 0, borderTopClass  : operator === 'fas fa-equals'}] in

Here is the code with the ngFor

```
<div class="ng-container" *ngFor="let operator of operatorList; let i = index">
    <mat-list-item 
        fxLayoutAlign="start" 
        style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;" 
        [ngClass]="{ totalrow:i%2 != 0, odd:i%2 == 0, borderTopClass   : operator === 'fas fa-equals'}">
            <i class="{{operator}}"></i>
    </mat-list-item>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the error you've mentioned. Maybe it could be a typo/formatting issue. But providing you a working version of code for what you want to achieve in case it helps:

https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-uydqp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess a commenter needs a deeper explanation of how this works.

```
<div [ngClass]="{
  'is-active': condition,
  'is-inactive': !condition,
  'multiple': condition && anotherCondition,
}">
```

`multiple` class will apply when two conditions are both met. Not just one but both.

You could add a third like this: `'multiple': condition && anotherCondition && thirdCondition`

Here's a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngclass-fix-for-stackoverflow-answer?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html) of the OP's code working as he expected and without error. If I can help more pleas let me know.